# What actions could be moved to hosts:all

Tags: ansible

I have spent some time with Ansible so far and have a few projects to be automated, but I have never seen a list of things that will be applied to every host(for instance, roles), and that won't (vars?) using `hosts: all`.
If I am mistaken and missed sorry, but I believe it would be nice to have these things listed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I made a research, and with `hosts: all` you can:

- run pre_tasks, post_tasks and tasks
- setup `become` and `become_user`
- define handlers(obviously)
- define roles

You can't:

- define vars and vars files to be used in each hosts; apparently you have to set them explicitly for each host.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to reword your question for clarity. I believe what you're looking for is some kind of safe insight to the actions that would be taken by your playbook. In this case, a **dry-run** might serve your use-case.

example: `ansible-playbook rusanov-test.yml --check`

you can also add a `-v`, `-vv` or `-vvv` to view increasingly verbose output.

[reference here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_checkmode.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug all the things, just run your playbook as

`ansible-playbook <playbook_name> -vvvv`.